# Karma exits with code 1 when it doesnt execute any spec tests

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, gulp-karma

Karma test runs fine but exits with code `1` if `0 of 0` tests are run. Does anyone know how to return exit code `0` and normally exit in this case? Using `gulp-karma` which fails the task when no specs are run.

Comment: I solved it by creating unit tests! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gulpfile, replace the "throw err" on the error callback in the your gulp test task with "this.emit('end')".

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  return gulp.src(testFiles)
    .pipe(karma({
      configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
      action: 'run'
  }))
  .on('error', function(err) {
    throw err;
  });
});
```

so your test task now looks like;

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  return gulp.src(testFiles)
    .pipe(karma({
      configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
      action: 'run'
  }))
  .on('error', function(err) {
   this.emit('end');
  });
});
```

Comment: This would make the gulp task swallow every error, no? But the asker only wants to ignore the 'no-test' case.

Comment: This is not the answer.

Answer (score 39):

There is a [configuration option](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html) that allows for empty test suites. Just add

```
failOnEmptyTestSuite: false
```

to your `karma.conf.js` and the process will exit with exit code 0.

BR
Chris

Comment: This is the real answer to the question as asked.

Comment: This solves the question! But note, it still does output "0 of 0 ERROR" to the console in red coloring, which can be visually misleading.